# Rails convert string containing datetime to date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a String which contains the following string `2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC` I want to change it into a date object so that is should look like this `03-06-2012` and the same is to be converted in String `03-06-2012` so that the jquery datepicker can take it.

All this conversion needs to be done at view .html.erb

Comment: `Date.parse("2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC") #=> Tue, 06 Mar 2012` Ruby 1.9.3 / Rails 3 ; `Date.parse("2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC").strftime("%d-%m-%Y") # => "06-03-2012"`

Answer (score 6):

```
Date.parse("2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: well I am newbie to front end and rails both
when I do the given below it works

    <%= text_field_tag map1[:field_name], "#{Date.parse("2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")}"%>


but when i try using a variable instead of that hard coded value it breaks 

    <%= text_field_tag map1[:field_name], "#{Date.parse("value").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")}", :class => 'blr', :placeholder => map1[:field_codes], :class =>"datepicker"%>

Comment: you should tell me the exact error it gives, and also the content of your value variable. Be sure your variable name isn't inside double quotes

Comment: Well as I already told I am a newbie. How can I check what error is thrown at view. It just fails to load

Comment: value="2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC"

Comment: It should not fail to show, it should print the error at browser. Is your project running in development environment?. You could, elseway, look if the output of rails s in console tells you anything

Comment: yes it is running in development env. and the console is not giving me any error message related to this problem

Answer (score 3):

You can do this

```
date = DateTime.now
puts date.to_date.to_s
```

which gives "2013-08-21"

Comment: Not quite what the OP needs, but a straightforward way.

Answer (score 2):

```
date = Date.parse('2012-03-06 00:00:00 UTC')
# => Tue, 06 Mar 2012
date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
# => "06-03-2012"
```